# How to find the number of elements in least common multiple problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

The problem is as follows:

> Over a table there is a certain number of muffins, if we count them by
>   multiples of four the remainder is three. If we count them by
>   multiples of six the remainder is five but if we count them by
>   multiples of ten the remainder is nine. What is the least number of
>   muffins over the table?

What I tried to do is to build up the equations to get the supposed number as follows:

$\textrm{n is defined as the number of muffins}$

$4k+3=n$

$6k+5=n$

$10k+9=n$

Then i equated those to get the value of $k$.

$4k+3=6k+5$

$2k=-2$

$k=-1$

$10k+9=6k+5$

$4k=-4$

$k=-1$

$4k+3=10k+9$

$6k=-6$

$k=-1$

However in all cases I reach to $-1$ and it does not seem to be reasonable to use it in any of those equations. I'm lost in this one can somebody help me to address this situation the easiest way possible?.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting a nonsensical answer is because there is no reason why the values of $k$ in your three equations should be the same. All you really know is that there are integers $a,b,c$ such that
$$\begin{align}
n &= 3 + 4a, \\
n &= 5 + 6b, \\
n &= 9 + 10c.
\end{align}$$
To solve this, you can iteratively substitute. From the first equation $n = 3 + 4a$, we see that
$$ 3 + 4a = 5 + 6b,$$
or rather that $2a = 1 + 3b = 4 + 3(b-1) = 4 + 3b'$ for some integer $b'$. Note that $b'$ must be even so that the right hand side is even (which must occur as the left hand side is even). So we can write $b' = 2b''$ for some integer $b''$.

Then from $2a = 4 + 6b''$, we have that $a = 2 + 3b''$. Substituting into $n = 3 + 4a$, we find that $n = 3 + 4(2 + 3b'') = 11 + 12b''$ for some integer $b''$. It's annoying to write $b''$, so I'll write $d$ instead of $b''$.

The point is that the information that
$$\begin{align}
n &= 3 + 4a \\
n &= 5 + 6b
\end{align}$$
is contained within the single equation $n = 11 + 12d$. Indeed, if $n = 11 + 12d$ for some integer $d$, then its remainder upon dividing by $4$ is $3$, and its remainder upon dividing by $6$ is $5$. We showed the converse above. Thus from two equations, we have one.

Now we repeat, this time with
$$\begin{align}
n &= 11 + 12 d \\
n &= 9 + 10 c.
\end{align}$$
Equating, we see that $9 + 10c = 11 + 12d$, or rather that $5c = 1 + 6d$. As above, we massage the right hand side a bit and write $5c = 25 + 6(d - 4) = 25 + 6d'$. In this form, we see that $d'$ must be divisible by $5$ to make the right hand side divisible by $5$ (as the left hand side is divisible by $5$). So we can write $d' = 5 d''$ for some integer $d''$. Thus $5c = 25 + 30d''$, or rather $c = 5 + 6d''$. Writing $d''$ is annoying, so I use $e$ instead.

Then we have that $c = 5 + 6e$. Substituting into $n = 9 + 10c$, we have that
$$ n = 9 + 10(5 + 6e) = 59 + 60e.$$
Notice that if $n = 59 + 60e$, then dividing by $4$ leaves remainder $3$, dividing by $6$ leaves remainder $5$, and dividing by $10$ leaves remainder $9$. And to get $n = 59 + 60e$, we just massaged the equations above.

Thus the set of integers that leave the three necessary remainders are exactly those integers of the form $59 + 60e$. The smallest (positive) integer of this form is $59$. (Note that $-1$ is also of this form, and you found $-1$ by essentially guessing a value for $e$ at the start).

So the answer is $59$.

---

Addendum: the computations I performed were elementary, but they can seem a bit uninspired. But I knew to do this because I was modifying a proof of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), which would apply naively if $\gcd(4,6,10) = 1$ (which it's not). The computations feel more natural when considered in congruences. To see this, let's redo the first pair reduction using congruences.

So $n = 3 + 4a$ is the same as $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$, and $n = 5 + 6b$ is the same as $n \equiv 5 \mod 6$. So we are trying to solve the simultaneous congruence
$$\begin{align}
n &\equiv 3 \mod 4, \\
n &\equiv 5 \mod 6.
\end{align}$$
To do this we write $n = 3 + 4a$ and substitute into the second congruence, getting
$$ 3 + 4a \equiv 5 \pmod 6 \implies 2a \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies a \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$$
And thus $a = 2 + 3b$ for some $b$, so that $n = 3 + 4(2 + 3b) = 11 + 12 b$ for some $b$. Or rather $a \equiv 11 \pmod {12}$.

This is exactly as above, except without the various variable shenanigans I employed previously. The rest of the argument works the same.

Comment: Thanks for being very articulate into explaining how you get to the answer but I find the method a bit hard to follow. As you mentioned the thing here is demonstrating how to obtain the remainder upon dividing by all the combinations of numbers given but the way to get it is confusing. Let me explain, why in the third step a new variable $b'$ replaces $b$?. Its also confusing the necessity to use b'' for the new integer as well the use $d'$ and $d''$ therefore by the time I reach to $59+60e$ I'm lost.

Comment: The second part which uses $mod$ is even harder. How exactly $2a\equiv 1(\mod 3)$ becomes into $a\equiv 2(\mod 3)$?. I suppose that the rest is repeat the same with the following equation and we reach to $59$ but as I explained I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell These are very specific, good questions, and so I'm happy to answer. I use $b'$ to mean $b - 1$ (and later, $d' = d-4$). I introduce these labels since we then think about the divisibility of $b'$ (and later, $d'$), and I find it more natural to think of $b'$ being divisible by $2$ then $b-1$ to be divisible by $2$. These are just convenience variables. The important aspect is that from $2a = 4 + 3(b-1)$, we have that $2(a-2) = 3(b-1)$. As $2$ doesn't divide $3$, it must divide $b-1 = b'$. By the definition of divisibility we write $b-1 = 2b''$ for some other integer $b''$.

Comment: The other substitutions are the same. Concerning your second question concerning mod: one can multiply both sides of a congruence by anything and the congruence remains true. So multiplying by $2$ changes $2a \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ into $4a \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, and noting that $4a \equiv a \bmod 3$ shows that $a \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. Others might phrase this as saying that since $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, there is some number $x$ such that $2x \equiv 1 \bmod 3$. Multiplying both sides by that $x$ gives $a \equiv 1x \bmod 3$ (and here it happens that $x \equiv 2 \bmod 3$).

Comment: Okay now I get what you meant by using those labels but I'm stuck on how $b-1$ was obtained. In your answer it is stated as.$2a=1+3b$ then $2a=4+3(b-1)$ but I don't know how you get into that equation. By following the second part I got the impression $mod$ is also affected by the operation as $\mod 6$ becomes into $\mod 3$. The part where you say $4a \equiv 2 \mod 3$ is $4a \equiv a mod 3$ means $2$ is suddenly a?. At this point I'm assuming that each time I encounter an expression like $2a \equiv 1 \mod 3$ then $a \equiv 2 \mod 3$. But what about i.e $5a \equiv 9 \mod 3$?. How to solve that?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I suspect you notice that if you just multiply out $4 + 3(b-1)$ then you see it's equal to $1 + 3b$, and so presumably you are asking *why* I chose to write it as $b-1$ instead of, say, $b-2$. My goal was to add something to the other number ($1$ in this case), to make it divisible by the coefficient of $a$ (which is $2$ in this case). This isn't a unique choice --- you could just as well have chosen to write it as $2a = -2 + 3(b+1)$, and the rest of the work would be about the same.

Comment: Concerning the mod question: immediately reducing mod $3$ you find that $5a \equiv 9 \bmod 3$ is the same as $2a \equiv 0 \bmod 3$, with clear solution $a \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. I don't know if this was a particular question you had. Generically, you can see how to solve those after looking up "linear congruence equation".

Comment: It took me the whole day to figure out the way how you did it but now I understand. However I still find the method a bit of guess-estimate (if you know what i mean) because in every step we have to modify the equation so that both terms in the right side are divisible by the term in the left side and this process can be prone to errors as we introduce a new variable and so on, provided the new variable is accompanied by a constant which indicates the divisibility.

Comment: I'm not very fond of $mod$ operator and it was not very clear the answer from the particular question I did mentioned earlier. Why $2a \equiv 0 \mod 3$? I'm still pondering whether this procedure can be applied in other circumstances let's say if the last equation is $n=8+10c$. Can still the problem be solved?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell If there is a solution, the two methods I presented will always work to find it. It is possible to have a system without a solution. If $n = 8 + 10c$, then there is no solution. You can see this immediately as $n = 8 + 10c$ means that $n$ is even, but $n = 3 + 4a$ means that $n$ is odd. These cannot both be true. When trying to use the methods I described above to solve the modified system, you'll find it is impossible to isolate one of the variables (or just arrive at an inconsistency if you use the mod point of view).

Comment: I would like to say that I'm not memorizing the methods you proposed but rather learning if I could make a generalization so next time I encounter something similar I can tackle it the way you had shown. The observation you pointed about odds and evens its something I didn't took into consideration when I wrote my question, Regarding linear congruence equation you mentioned I'm adding this to my list of things to review so I can better understand the second method you used.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot compete with [mixedmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754/mixedmath)'s more general solution, one interesting aspect of the problem leapt out at me:

$n=4\alpha-1$
$n=6\beta-1$
$n=10\gamma-1$
For $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{N}$

So... $n+1=4\alpha=6\beta=10\gamma$ which is to say that $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is divisible by $2, 3$ and $5$.  As the problem asks for the *least* value of $n$ then we're back on the subject of least common multiple.
$$\text{i.e.}\quad\frac{n+1}{2}=\mathrm{lcm}(2,3,5)=30$$

However I suspect the problem was structured so as to allow this approach.